# Какие явные преимущества использования App Bundle в приложении?

Tags: android, google-play

Google Play уже не в первый раз настойчиво предлагает использовать в приложении [AppBundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle).

Начал разбираться, но не увидел много критериев и причин использовать его у меня в проекте, поэтому прошу подсказать, кто уже столкнулся или успел заметить больше чем я.

Один из основных критериев который я успел для себя выявить, это возможность загружать функции *On Demand*(по требованию). Кстати которые очень хорошо описаны [здесь](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/on-demand-dynamic-delivery/index.html#0).

Но исходя из этого единственный критерий который мне приходит в голову это то что можно подгружать те или модули по надобности.

Также не совсем понятно как происходит выбор расширений экрана/конкретной платформы при скачивании приложения с Google Play Store.

Comment: @Kromster Определить критерии использования `AppBundle` в приложениях

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью app bundle можно легко оптимизировать размер приложения, при этом не нужно будет вносить какие-либо изменения в код. Android App Bundle включает весь скомпилированный код и ресурсы, отсеивая затем то, что не нужно конкретному устройству.

Comment: отсеивает сам google play? ну то есть я залил apk, после чего пользователь его скачал конкретно для своей платформы? мне нажо это как то контролировать?

Comment: @Morozov именно

Comment: а что всё таки по разделению на модули? 
На сколько это ок и надо вообще, с теми же опциями подкачки функционала по запросу.
По сути я предлагаю пользователю легкий apk который ему нужно будет самому докачать если что?

Если более конкретно задать вопрос,  то плюсы разбивки на модули по идее это лишь возможность тетстить блоки приложения по отдельности?

Comment: @Morozov на одном устройстве нужен ресурс,на другом устройстве не нужен. Например если мы говорим про внутренние ресурсы либ от самого гугла. В итоге происходит оптимизация размера.